# While trying to trap the Event for Product Detail page in Magento facing issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php, event-observer, mysql, product-view

> I am using magento 1.9.1.0 in that i want to trap the event observer
>   for product detail page .So for that we had created a custom observer
>   and it is working properly for target_path url present in
>   core_url_rewrite like (1.e
>   catalog/product/view/id/1241641/category/352/store/2) but when i am
>   using request path for the same (i.e
>   /women/accessories/handbags/bag.html) then we are getting "The page
>   you requested was not found".

**My custom Module details are given below**

**Observer.php**

```
class Gamer_CustomProduct_Model_Observer {

    public function getProductView(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

            echo "In getProductView";
            exit;

            }

}
```

**Config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gamer_CustomProduct>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Gamer_CustomProduct>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <customproduct>
                <class>Gamer_CustomProduct_Model</class>
            </customproduct>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_init_before> 
                <observers>
                    <catalog_controller_product_init_before_handler> 
                        <type>model</type> 
                        <class>customproduct/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
                        <method>getProductView</method>  
                    </catalog_controller_product_init_before_handler>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_init_before>
        </events>

    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: what your problem "/women/accessories/handbags/bag.html 404 issue" or 'catalog_controller_product_init_before' not fire

Comment: Hi Amit,  when I type Target Path in browser address bar it works. However when I type request path I am unable to trap the event. We want to trap the event when 'request path' is entered in browser for a product.

Comment: k can you please  tell me what will be happen whenever hit /women/accessories/handbags/bag.html  on browser

Comment: ideally it should navigate to product detail page. In this case it will show up details of the bag. However currently since I am not able to trap the event I am getting 404 not found page.

Comment: That mean your issue in url_rewrite . Surely /women/accessories/handbags/bag.html  not rewrite path of this product page.Better idea to go `core_url_rewrite`  table  and the the url of product search by product id.

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do? I mean tell us why you need to capture a specific product page. There might be an easier way to do it than observing `catalog_controller_product_init_before`.

Comment: We have data present in core_url_rewrite table for this case. However we do not have product data in this database. We are requesting product details information from another magento website. In our database we have category information and URL rewrite information of another magento website.

Comment: In this table magento save url of product and categories.run this query at db `SELECT * FROM core_url_rewrite where product_id=YOURPRODUCTID and store_id=2`.check urls of that produdtcs

Comment: @Marius - We have our magento website (A) and another magento website (B). Requirement we have received is we do not wish to have product data in website A. What we are doing is we are doing API calls to fetch the data from website B. We are getting Product listing information correctly. When we navigate to product detail then in the browser url we see 'request path' from core_url_rewrite. However when we open this link we are getting 404 error. Please let us know if you need more information.

Comment: @AmitBera yes we have the data in table for the given product id

Comment: Can you remove this `<!-- observers class alias -->` in config.xml, sometime extra spaces plays role.

Comment: @ Adarsh Khatr still no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should observe some generic event, such as `controller_front_send_response_before` and check if 404 page is going to be rendered. I show you an approach using a 301 redirect

```
public function yourFunction($observer){

    $resp = $observer->getEvent()->getFront()->getAction()->getRequest();
    if ($resp->getActionName() == 'noRoute'){

        $requestUri = $resp->getRequestString();
        // match this with your url rewrites table
        // maybe you should want to trim the / in $requestUri, print_r() it
        // if it is found then...
        header("Location: " . Mage::getBaseUrl() . $yourMatchedUrl, 301);
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: catalog_controller_product_view even for this event if we provide target_url_path then it is working but for request_url_path it is not working and we would be entering request url path in the address bar

Comment: mmm... In a clean installation you'd always see a `Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()` call if you debug in view.phtml template, independently of the url provided

Comment: I think your problem is your rewrite urls are not working, reading your comment: "The page you requested was not found". But that's not about your module or your observer, that's about your Magento configuration, indexes, etc...

Comment: i want to show this product details on Website A which doesn't consist of any product details in data base it consist of only core_url_rewrites from website B so i want to just use Request_path_url from core_url_rewrites and call my website A custom observer so that from there i can make a call to a api request to website b and fetch product details and display it on my custom view page of Website A

Comment: ok please update it

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Hi @Raul Sanchez WE will try this solution and will update you. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25191/discussion-between-rupesh-deotale-and-raul-sanchez).

Comment: Hi @Raul Sanchez , Thanks this solution, its working for me. Can you please tell us how can we render the custom template without changing URL in the browser address bar.

Comment: You'd ask a new concrete question, providing the specifications & details of your project

Comment: Hi @Raul Sanchez  i had posted the question for this can you please go through it and give me some solution on it. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72219/redirect-to-specific-controller-from-observer-without-changing-my-current-browse