# Redirect to specific controller from observer without changing my current browser Url

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, url-rewrite, redirect-url

I had written a observer to trap product view page event and it is working fine.Now in that code i want to call a controller and pass the product id in it and render the custom view.phtml file, so how can i call that controller without changing my current browser url and render the view.phtml file on same url.

**My Observer Code is Given Below**

```
public function getProductView(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{         
      $resp = $observer->getEvent()->getFront()->getAction()->getRequest();
      $requestUri = $resp->getRequestString();            
       if ($resp->getActionName() == 'noRoute'){
           $requestUri = $resp->getRequestString();
           $requestUri = ltrim($requestUri, '/');
           $this->db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM core_url_rewrite WHERE request_path like '%".$requestUri."%'";
           $data = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
           // header("Location: " . Mage::getBaseUrl() . "customproduct/prodId=".$data[0]['product_id'], 301);
           // exit;

           //header('location:'.MAGE::getBaseurl()."customproduct",301);

           //Edit: action not passed in to this event; passed in generic generate_blocks event
             //Mage::getUrl('customproduct');
           exit;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by below code:

```
$identifier=trim($resp->getPathInfo(),'/');
    $resp
    ->setModuleName('ModuleRouterName')  
                ->setControllerName('controllerName')
                ->setActionName('YOurActioname');

//$resp->setDispatched(true);  

$resp->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $identifier
        );
return true;
```

**setDispatched(true/false) not sure..**

Comment: Hi @Amit Bera thanks for your reply i have tried your solution   $resp->setModuleName('customproduct')  
            ->setControllerName('Index')
            ->setActionName('index')->setDispatched(true);  but it is giving me white screen

Comment: update ..check now

Comment: Hi @ Amit Bera, I tried this suggestion however Index controller is not called. When I go to browser and type {domain}/customproduct/index then index controller is getting called and I can see messge that has been echo'ed. However When we trap the event in observer, then from there index controller is not being called.

Comment: Part of the var_dump of $resp is                                                                                                 protected '_dispatched' => boolean true
  protected '_module' => string 'customproduct' (length=13)
  protected '_moduleKey' => string 'module' (length=6)
  protected '_controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
  protected '_controllerKey' => string 'controller' (length=10)
  protected '_action' => string 'index' (length=5)
  protected '_actionKey' => string 'action' (length=6)

Comment: Hi @ Amit Bera do you have any idea how to do it